# Is it possible to apply Authcache caching to elements in page.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, caching

In applying Authcache settings to an existing site I have encountered a problem where certain items hard-coded into the theme's `page.tpl.php` need to be personalised for each user. I could do it by moving those components into blocks and/or panels, but they are quite complex and I was wondering if a better approach would be to do it via the Authcache API using the authcache_usercookie.module example as a starting point.

Here is an example of the code I would like to personalise:

```
<?php if($page['topics_tab']): ?>
<div class="tabs-menu collapse hidden-print" id="topics-collapse-tab">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
        <?php print render($page['topics_tab']); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is it possible (easy? difficult?) to modify `page.tpl.php` to make Authcache cache this snippet for each user, or should I redo the page using blocks/panels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to redo the page with blocks (or panels). The Authcache User Cookie example is rather basic and does not demonstrate how to *deliver* fragments from the custom front controller.

Regrettably there is still not enough documentation on how to roll your own custom fragment renderer. Look at the `api.php` files and read through the numerous submodules to get the picture.

Last but not least, there are some (closed) support requests in the ticket tracker covering this issue, e.g. [#2780485](https://www.drupal.org/node/2780485).